# Can you install Google Chrome on an iOS Device

Tags: ios, google-chrome

Is it possible to install Google Chrome web browser on an iOS device?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can now install [Google Chrome on an iOS Device](http://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/chrome/id535886823?mt=8).

Do note that it does not use the Chrome Rendering engine, but uses the Safari webkit. The "killer feature" though is that it has syncing with your Google Account.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

No. It's not possible to run Chrome in iOS.

I don't see why you'll want to run Chrome, even if it exists.

Safari for iPhone uses WebKit, the same rendering engine that Chrome uses. There shouldn't be much difference between the two. Safari is plenty fast on the iPhone.

The only other browser available for iPhone is Opera.

Comment: I have a feeling that apple on allowed Opera through the app store approval process because it is so poor and they wanted to show them up

Comment: Haha, that's a good one @gnuchu.

Comment: @Gnuchu - no, it was not political. Opera Mini is actually a remote viewer for a web browser session running on Opera's servers. Due to this, it passed all the Apple tests and they had no grounds to reject it. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opera-mini-web-browser/id363729560?mt=8

Comment: @gnuchu, I concur. That's why Apple store is not showing Chrome because Chrome beats Safari to death.

Comment: @Graviton: please unaccept this answer, as it is no longer true; see jrg's answer.

Comment: This answer is no longer true. Chrome is now on iOS. ;-) And I love the incognito tabs. But it still needs some polish.

Answer (score 1):

As it is not available in the app store (at least not here in Germany), it is not possible. Maybe there is an app or possibility for jailbroken iPhones, but I doubt it.

Answer (score -1):

It is not and I doubt that there will ever be such a port, because the model Chrome is based on is that each tab is run as a separate process. As there is no true multitasking in the iPhone (available in public APIs, that is) such app would not be possible to do.

If Google ever releases something like that (which would not be approved in the App Store, with the current rules, but for argument's sake let's say it's released as an ad-hoc distribution, or as source code) it would work very differently, thus being a different product with the same brand

Comment: Might want to consider deleting this, it makes you look bad :]

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but what I said is still true. The current Chrome browser on the App Store is a wrapper on top of the same webkit that Mobile Safari uses. It doesn't come from Chromium, the only similarity being likely the bookmark syncing code and other peripheral code.

Answer (score -2):

Google would have to first properly release a chrome app for android before even thinking about an iOS app. Would be shooting themselves in the foot otherwise.

Whether or not Apple would approve it would be another story.