# How do I install the mobile version of Google Chrome on my iPod touch 4th generation?

Tags: ios, applications, ipod, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you install Google Chrome on an iOS Device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/can-you-install-google-chrome-on-an-ios-device)

I want to install Chrome on my iPod touch 4th generation.

How do I do that?

Comment: There is no official Google Chrome app, so you'll have to specify what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox haven't been developed for iOS yet, but you could try Dolphin Browser. It's very similar to Chrome, and you can download extensions for it.

Opera Mini and Murcury Web Browser (quite similar to Desktop Safari) are another couple of nice alternatives to Mobile Safari, and Atomic Web Browser is slightly better than Safari, but doesn't have many features.

If you want to watch Flash videos on your iPad, try out Skyfire. It's limited, but it does what it says.
If you want an interface which looks like Chrome, you might like [Diigo Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ichromy-chrome-style-web-browser/id432838105?mt=8#). Here's a [review of the app](http://ipadinsight.com/ipad-app-reviews/ichromy-chrome-style-web-browser-for-ipad) which may help.

[image]

You could search for "browser" on the app store, but realize that most of the applications that you find will still be using the same rendering engine that Apple developed. It's only the stuff around the rendering engine that will look different.

There are some rumors that Firefox will eventually release an iOS version.

Personally though, I prefer Dolphin as my favorite. :3

## [Dolphin Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/dolphin-browser-for-ipad/id460812023?mt=8)

- Gestures: create a personal symbol to access the websites you use the most
- Visit your favorite sites with one touch.
- Tabbed browsing
- Bookmarks Bar
- Full Screen Mode

[image]

Comment: -1 What's with the complete copy+paste of my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Chrome is currently not available for iOS. Although, Safari itself uses the same Webkit rendering base as Chrome.

There are third party browsers in the App Store, but all of these are still just using a WebView (a la Safari) as their backend. The only one that may not is Opera, but that is because everything is rendered on their servers.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox haven't been developed for iOS yet, but you could try Dolphin Browser. It's very similar to Chrome, and you can download extensions for it. Personally, Dolphin is my favorite. Opera Mini and Murcury Web Browser (quite similar to Desktop Safari) are another couple alternatives to Mobile Safari, and Atomic Web Browser is slightly better than Safari, but doesn't have many features. If you want to watch Flash videos on your device, try out Skyfire. It's limited, but it does what it says. There are plenty more browsers out there for iOS, but these are the ones I use most.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is in the App Store, that will involve first jail breaking your device, and then compiling it yourself (or else finding a trusted source). I think you'll find it impossible at present.